# Deleting Text Substings with a Wildcards r

Tags: r, string, str-replace, gsub

I would like to delete a portion of several text strings which are part of a vector.  The instances I would like to delete are #.##oz.  Where # is any integer between 1 and 9 (inclusive).

`FoodVector <- c("kraft easy mac cup 2.05oz each", "tuna kit bumble bee 3.05oz each", "lance cheddar cheese wh grain 1.50oz each", "some item 1.0oz")`

The result should be:

```
[1] kraft easy mac cup each 
[2] tuna kit bumble bee each
[3] lance cheddar cheese wh grain each
[4] some item 1.0oz
```

For something like this I would normally use gsub() or str-replace().  However I can't figure out the wild card language. For instance

```
gsub("*.**oz", "", FoodVector)
```

Results in:

```
Error in gsub("*.**", "", FoodVector) : 
  invalid regular expression '*.**', reason 'Invalid use of repetition operators'
```

Comment: I really like https://regexone.com/ to learn regex (aka regular expressions) for text manipulation. In about 30 minutes you can learn 80% of any regex you'll ever need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use gsub to delete all instances of a single digit, then a `.`, then two digits, then a space.

Note: Your description says integers between 1 and 9 and doesn't mention a space. This solution looks for digits between 0 and 9 and also looks for a space, in order to match the result shown in the question

```
gsub('\\d{1}\\.\\d{2}oz ', '', FoodVector)
# [1] "kraft easy mac cup each"           
# [2] "tuna kit bumble bee each"          
# [3] "lance cheddar cheese wh grain each"
# [4] "some item 1.0oz"
```

To address Rui's point below, you could allow the space to be before or after the d.ddoz

```
FoodVector <- c(FoodVector, '1.23oz some words', 'more words 3.45oz')

gsub('\\d{1}\\.\\d{2}oz | \\d{1}\\.\\d{2}oz', '', FoodVector)
# [1] "kraft easy mac cup each"           
# [2] "tuna kit bumble bee each"          
# [3] "lance cheddar cheese wh grain each"
# [4] "some item 1.0oz"                   
# [5] "some words"                        
# [6] "more words"
```

Comment: Isn't the space in front safer? If there's no *" each"* at the end, the space after *"oz"* will fail to match the string. (I know that it's not the cases posted, just saying that the space before matches both cases.)

Comment: I'll leave this post open for the customary 24 hours., but this is exactly what I needed.